# How can I use Python to get the contents inside of this span tag?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I'm trying to scrape the information from Google Translate as a learning exercise and I can't figure out how to reach the content of this span tag.

```
<span title="Hello" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ebeff9'"                                  
      onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'">
    Hallo
</span>
```

How would I use Python to reach into the contents. Since the 'title' parameter of this span is dynamic, I guess I can target that as a point of entry?

For example trying to translate: 
Hi, welcome to my house. Would you like a glass of tea or maybe some biscuits?

results in the following html output:

```
<span title="Hi, welcome to my house." 
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ebeff9'" 
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'">
    Hallo, mein Haus begrÃ¼ÃŸen zu dÃ¼rfen. 
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [BeautifulSoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/3.0.8.1)

Comment: Will do! Thanks! Wait, I just realized I never imported a different .py file. How would I 'import' this to my project?

Comment: You can use Python package manager to install it and then import it in your program.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyInstall

Comment: B soup comes with an setup script; just run 'python setup.py install'.

Comment: Please include more than just a link in your answer. Why is `BeautifulSoup` the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def gettext(html):
    for sp in myhtml.split("</span>"):
       if "<span" in sp:
          return sp.rsplit(">")[-1].strip()

myhtml="""
<span title="Hello" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ebeff9'"
      onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'">
    Hallo
</span>
"""

print gettext(myhtml)

myhtml="""
<span title="Hi, welcome to my house."
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ebeff9'"
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'">
    Hallo, mein Haus begrÃ¼ÃŸen zu dÃ¼rfen.
</span>
"""

print gettext(myhtml)
```

output

```
$ python mytranslate.py
Hallo
Hallo, mein Haus begrÃ¼ÃŸen zu dÃ¼rfen.
```

Answer (score 0):

Python ships with a few XML and HTML parsers.

- **Element Tree Parser**

  - This is supposed to be the most pythonic method of parsing XML files.
  - [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree)
- **DOM XML Parsers**

  - [xml.dom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#module-xml.dom)
  - [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#module-xml.dom.minidom)
- **SAX XML Parser**

  - [xml.sax](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html#module-xml.sax)
- **Expat XML Parser**

  - [xml.parsers.expat](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat.html#module-xml.parsers.expat)
- **Simple HTML and XHTML Parser**

  - [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html#module-HTMLParser)
- **Third Party Parsers**

  - If you don't like any of the parsers included with python.
  - [lxml](http://www.codespeak.net/lxml)
  - [BeautifulSoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/3.0.8.1)

I would suggest that you look at the parsers that come with Python first, then look at third party parsers if you don't find any of the included modules acceptable.